# Runtime upcasting failure from Thinking in Java

Tags: java, runtime-error, upcasting

When running this code, why would it have runtime error?
The array is defined to hold Fruit, but how can I not give fruit to it after I initialized it with apple?

```
class Fruit{}
class Apple extends Fruit{}
class Jonathan extends Apple{}
class Orange extends Fruit{}

public class CovariantArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fruit[] fruit = new Apple[10];
        fruit[0] = new Apple();
        fruit[1] = new Jonathan();
        try {
            fruit[0] = new Fruit();
        } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
        try {
            fruit[0] = new Orange();
        } catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
    }
}
```

Comment: The array is an `Apple[]`.  Why would you expect it to be able to hold something that's not a kind of `Apple`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is because you are trying to put a `Fruit` and `Orange` inside an `Apple`.
You can only put stuff inside `Apple[]` if its really an apple e.g.

```
class Fruit{}
class Apple extends Fruit{}
class Jonathan extends Apple{}
class Orange extends Fruit{}
class BigApple extends Apple{}
class BigGreenApple extends BigApple{}

public class CovariantArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fruit[] fruit = new Apple[10];
        fruit[0] = new Apple();
        fruit[1] = new Jonathan(); // no error here since Jonathan is an Apple
        fruit[2] = new BigApple(); // still Apple
        fruit[3] = new BigGreenApple(); // no worries - still Apple
        fruit[4] = new Orange(); // Oops - Orange is a Fruit but its not Apple so error here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to put it in array type:

```
fruit[0] = (Fruit) new Apple();
```